# How to identify operators using isdigit in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am making a program to check if the input given by user is positive or negative.

I have used isdigit to print "wrong choice/input".If user inputs a string.

Program is working fine... but one block is not working that is of negative number.

Whenever I give a negative value it shows wrong choice because isdigit checks for integers in a string but not symbols.

How can I fix this?

Comment: could you please give an example?

Comment: please share code

Comment: `isdigit` is not an "is this a number" test. It is an "is this string composed of digit characters" test. It is almost always the wrong tool for the job, since the job is usually to check whether a string can be parsed as a number in some format, not to check whether a string is made of digit characters.

Answer (score 0):

You could first check the first character and if it's a minus sign only apply `isdigit()` to the rest of the string, ie:

```
# py2/py3 compat
try:
    # py2
    input = raw_input
except NameError:
    # py3
    pass

while True:
    strval = input("please input a number:").strip()
    if strval.startswith("-"):
        op, strval = strval[0], strval[1:]
    else:
        op = "+"
    if not strval.isdigit():
        print("'{}' is not a valid number".format(strval))
        continue
    # now do something with strval and op
```

But it's much simpler to just try and pass `strval` to `int()`, which will either return an integer or raise a `ValueError` if the string is not a valid representation of an integer:

```
# py2/py3 compat
try:
    # py2
    input = raw_input
except NameError:
    # py3
    pass

while True:
    strval = input("please input a number:")
    try:
        intval = int(strval.strip())
    except ValueError:
        print("'{}' is not a valid number".format(strval))
        continue
   # now do something with intval
```